# React private route function is called twice

Tags: reactjs

If user is logged in, render the component. If not, render login page. I notice, however, that this function is called twice. The first time, `useAuthDataContext()` is *null*. The second time, I get the correct object back.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, ...options }) => {
  const { userData } = useAuthDataContext()
  console.log(userData)
  const finalComponent = userData != null ? component : Login
  return (
    <Route {...options}  component={finalComponent} />
  )
};

export default PrivateRoute
```

I have rewritten this function as follows. Here, `PrivateRoute2` is called only once, and `useAuthDataContext()` returns *null*.

```
const PrivateRoute2 = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { userData } = useAuthDataContext()
  console.log(userData)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        userData != null ? (
          <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: props.location }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    )
  }
```

Here is my useAuthDataContext() implementation that is causing the rerender:

```
export const AuthDataContext = createContext(null)
const initialAuthData = {}

const AuthDataProvider = props => {

  const [authData, setAuthData] = useState(initialAuthData)

  useLayoutEffect( (props) => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      try {
        const userData = await authService.isAuthenticated()
        setAuthData( {userData})
      } catch (err) {
        setAuthData({})
      }
    }
    getUser()
  }, [])

  const onLogout = () => {
    setAuthData(initialAuthData)
  }

  const onLogin = newAuthData => {
    const userData = newAuthData
    setAuthData( {userData} )
  }

  const authDataValue = useMemo(() => ({ ...authData, onLogin, onLogout }), [authData])
  return <AuthDataContext.Provider value={authDataValue} {...props} />
}

export const useAuthDataContext = () => useContext(AuthDataContext)
export default AuthDataProvider
```

Comment: Is it *actually* rendered twice, or are you just seeing two console logs for each? Try placing the console.log in an `useEffect` with no dependency array.

Comment: "Try placing the console.log in an useEffect with no dependency array" >> it only console.log once. However, I do see the Login component rendered followed by the actual component.

Comment: Then it seems your `useAuthDataContext` is updating and triggering the rerender, can you include that hook logic, is it a custom hook? BTW, completely unrelated but also just want to point out neither of your snippets are Higher Order Components.

Comment: I added the `useAuthDataContext` function to the question. I do call an api that returns a promise.

Comment: Well, the initial state of `authData` is null, and then it changes state (as expected). So how do I avoid seeing the Login component being rendered before the actual component? @DrewReese

Comment: I think adding *some* "isPending" "state" to it *could* potentially help solve it, but this adds another moving part. Basically you just need this third "state" display something other than the unauth component, or the login, when the authentication state is still being processed.

Comment: Is this normal react behavior?

Comment: What, rendering initial state, then rerendering when state (or props) updates? Yes, 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found one solution. See this post https://hackernoon.com/whats-the-right-way-to-fetch-data-in-react-hooks-a-deep-dive-2jc13230